# Postscript (.ps) support failed in Ubuntu 20.04.5

Tags: evince, postscript

Usually, I could open postscript .ps file using evince and convert them to pdf using ps2pdf. But suddenly after updating the Ubuntu it stopped working and both evince and ps2pdf shows this:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I have tried installed evince, gs, gv and even libgs9 to no avail.

Because one of my data-processing software only outputs ps files and it inconvenience me to not be able open it in Ubuntu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually solved the problem by purging all ghostscript related library and install necessary ones after that.